# Customize log messages using Loggerfactory in .net core application

Tags: azure, .net-core, log4net, azure-application-insights, loggerfactory

I have two console applications, one created in .Net framework 4.6. And other one in .net core 2.0. For logging, in .Net framework I'm using `log4Net`, in .net core I'm using Logger. This logger directly writes into Application Insights directly in Azure.

Now my question is, how to customize the logging messages using Logger. In `log4Net`, I have used `aiappender` and defined a conversion pattern based on my requirement. For example:

```
<appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <parameterName value="@Extra"/>      
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %level  :: Extra = %property{Extra} %message%newline"   />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

I have written this in the `log4net.config` and assigned values to `Extra` variable as below.

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["Extra"] = "SomeValue";
```

I want to do the similar customization for Logger in .Net core. This the sample code I have:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup()
    {
    } 
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ConsoleLogger>();
        logger.LogInformation("Executing Configure()");
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ILogger _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Executing Home/Index");

        return View();
    } 
}
```

In this code, if I want extra information similar to Log4Net pattern, how do I do it?

PS: I cannot change from logger to log4Net, as in reality the code is pretty big. Also I do not want to append the required information every time I'm logging some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [telemetry initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer) to add extra properties to all telemetry items, or to modify existing properties:

```
public class CustomInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        // modify trace message
        if (telemetry is TraceTelemetry trace)
            trace.Message = $"Modified Message: {trace.Message}"; 

        if (!(telemetry is ISupportProperties supportedTelemetry))
            return;

        // add custom property
        supportedTelemetry.Properties["MyProp"] = "MyValue";
    }
}
```

Add it to your services:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomInitializer>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

and make sure the Ilogger output is directed to App Insights:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Trace);

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```